# Python: Print a custom object

Tags: python, oop

I would like to print a custom object, for example

```
Class PR(object):
  def __init__(self,r):
     self.label = r.label   #label is a string
     self.types = [a,b,c]   #types is a string in list
     self.value = {a:1,b:2,c:3} #value is a string in dict
```

I want to overwrite the print function to print instance of PR class,when I overwrite the `__str__` function, I found it is hard to convert a list into a string.

I just want to invoke the python build-in function to print the list, is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: This might help: https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/551c137f51b887bbc4001b73

Answer (score 0):

Your `__str__` function has to return a string. If you just want to print the list named `types`, your class's `__str__` method should return `str(self.types)`.